# Laravel: Implement Auth::viaRemember() across the website

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

**Issue summary**

I would like to know how to properly implement user auth with Laravel's `Auth::viaRemember()` so it's checked across my website (through the remember cookie).

The token is set like this on login:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

which sets the **remember_xxxxxxxxxxx** cookie in the browser.

**Session config**

My session is configured to last 120 min after the browser was closed:

```
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

**Checking the remember cookie**

When the session expires after 120 min and the user comes to the page again, they should be authenticated via the remember token, maybe redirected to specific auth-filtered page. **How is the check actually done?**

1. Do I do it manually, e.g. by extending BaseController or applying a filter to all the routes?

**or**

2. Does Laravel deal with the cookie auth in the background?

Comment: Laravel handles this - as long as you run the `auth` filter

Comment: OK, that's very convenient. However, is it stated in the documentation or you got this info from the framework's code check? I will for sure test this anyway, but it's always nice to have actual grounds, so I can sleep like a baby.